# Conditional context in my first Django Class Based View

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am getting lost in Django Class Based Views.  I have a working function based view to create a user "profile".  A profile is an extension of a `User` object.  The function version is:

```
@verified_email_required
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #
        # should have *just* created a profile. save it then display it
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = request.user
            profile.save()

            my_render = render(request, 'Members/index.html', {
                'profile': profile,
                'profileState': "display"
            })
        else:
            #
            # form has issues. send it back to the create form to fix.
            my_render = render(request, 'Members/profile.html', {
                'profileForm': form,
                'profileState': "editForCreate"
            })
    else:
        #
        # no profile. Create one
        form = ProfileForm()

        my_render = render(request, 'Members/profile.html', {
            'profileForm': form,
            'profileState': "create"
        })

    return my_render
```

So now I want to replicate this general behaviour in a CBV.  The docs say that it will handle most of this by itself -- but I'm getting lost in the details.  So far I have:

```
@verified_email_required
class Create(CreateView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'Members/profile.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = 'Members/index.html'
    http_method_names = ['GET', 'POST']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = request.user
        profile.save()
```

I'll trust that it will handle the general POST and GET logic.  It will pass the `form` on to the `template_name` and there is the `success_url` for the successful creation case.

How do I pass the extra context "profileState" labels to the template and success url?  How do I send the "profile" to the success url?

My thought was to override `get_context_data` but I don't see how to "conditionally" pass in the labels and/or profile.

Also, in `form_valid` I need to access `request.user`.  How do I do that?

Comment: Careful, [CBV decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views) or not the same as with simple functions

Comment: In `form_valid`, you can use `self.request` and `self.form`.

Comment: And yes, just override `get_context_data`; you shouldn't need conditionals there.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try these in several hours.